# Grammar and adverbs question

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english, adverb-position

Is this question written correctly?

> Has the problem been solved already?

or maybe is this way

> Has the problem already been solved?

are both correct?

Comment: Have you put it into Grammarly to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are grammatically correct, although the first one seems in a negative sense (like you're shocked or disappointed/angry that the problem has been solved).
The second one seems to be delivering the same question in a more positive way.